# Why is mapped children component not rendering in enzyme wrapper using mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component(ExpansionView) that renders 25 child component(Expansion).

```
const ExpansionView = ({ expansion }: {[key: string]: boolean} = {}): ReactElement => {
  const validExpansion: StrArr = Object.keys(expansion).slice(0, -2); 

  // Generate multiple expansion components with respective name and img props
    const expansionGenerator = (expArr: StrArr): ReactElement[] => {
        return expArr.map((exp, i) => {
            return <ErrorBoundary key={i}>    
                    <Expansion 
                        name= {exp}
                        key = {exp} 
                        img = {allImage[i]} />
                 </ErrorBoundary>
        });
    }
  
  return(
        <StyledExpansionView id='expansionView'>
                {expansionGenerator(validExpansion)}
        </StyledExpansionView>
  )
  
  const mapStateToProps = (state: {expansions: {[key:string]: boolean}}) => {
    return {
        expansion: state.expansions,
    }
}
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpansionView);
```

The app works perfectly as is.

Jest/Enzyme test:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ExpansionView from '../components/ExpansionView';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Expansion from '../components/Expansion'
import ClearButton from '../components/ClearButton';
import CurrentRotationButton from '../components/CurrentRotationButton';

const initState = { allCard: [], expansions: [] };
const mockStore = configureStore();

describe('ExpansionView', () => {
    let expansion = {
        "Core": false,
        "Naxxramas": false,
        "Goblins vs Gnomes": false,
        "Blackrock Mountain": false,
        "The Grand Tournament": false, 
        "The League of Explorers": false,
        "Whispers of the Old Gods": false,
        "One Night in Karazhan": false,
        "Mean Streets of Gadgetzan": false,
        "Journey to Un'Goro": false,
        "Knights of the Frozen Throne": false,
        "Kobolds & Catacombs": false,
        "The Witchwood": false, 
        "The Boomsday Project": false,
        "Rastakhan's Rumble": false,
        "Rise of Shadows": false,
        "Saviors of Uldum": false,
        "Descent of Dragons": false,
        "Galakrond's Awakening": false,
        "Ashes of Outland": false,
        "Scholomance Academy": false,
        "Madness At The Darkmoon Faire": false,
        "Forged in the Barrens": false, 
        "United in Stormwind": false,
        "Fractured in Alterac Valley": false,
        "current rotation": false,
        "clear": false,
    }
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={mockStore(initState)}><ExpansionView /></Provider>);
    
  it('renders 25 expansions', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(Expansion).length).toBe(25); // returns 0
      expect(wrapper.find('img').length).toBe(25); // returns 0
   });
}
```

Enzyme configuration is in a separate setupTest.js file.

As seen in the last two lines, they both return 0. This tells me that jest is unable to map out those components at all for some reason. Is there a configuration required for mapping out child components for jest?

I have also tried shallow, but it does not make sense, as shallow will not render children.

I have been looking at the codebase as well as other similar questions on this site for the whole day. However, I still could not figure it out.

Please take a look. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: note: other child components that are rendered under ExpansionView in the same test file pass tests. They are not mapped out.

Comment: I have also tried:
expect(wrapper.children().length).toBe(25)
 expect(wrapper.hostNodes().length).toBe(25)
both are 0.

Comment: wrapper.debug() does not show any Expansion component's html tags.

Answer (score 0):

When using wrapper.debug(), no Expansion were being rendered in the HTML.

This was fixed by changing the initState from this:

```
const initState = { allCard: [], expansions: [] };
```

to this:

```
const initState = { allCard: [], expansions: expansion };
```

We are using a mockStore, and the ExpansionView component requires expansion state in props(from redux store), so we have to do the same in mockStore.

However, all the other attempts using .children() or .hostNodes() did not work in this case.